# Move and repalce a cell with 2 div tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following table

```html
 <table border='1'>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cell" id="1,1" draggable="true">
                        <div class="Name">A</div>
                        <div class="Number">l</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell" id="1,2" draggable="true">
                        <div class="Name">B</div>
                        <div class="Number">10</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
   </table>
```

What I want to do is be able to move the two div tags that are inside the cell to the other cell replacing the div tags that were previously there. I want to do this in a way that would allow me to add animation to the movement in the future.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: by "animation" do you mean drag and drop, or some animation after / during the drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

To move between 2 lists it ll be better to use the following link. Inspect it will give you easier way to achieve draggable lists

[Demo](http://neb.net/playground/dragdrop/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/ss9au2k9/1/

Basically you have to play with `dragstart`, `dragover` and `dragleave` events.

I've also wrapped your inner cell content in a `<div>` element and added some CSS classes.